# On the RPi Advanced setup page, what does mkcard.txt do?

Tags: setup

I have come across the [RPi Advanced Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup) but there are incomplete steps. For example, where can I find `mkcard.txt` from the **Advanced SD card setup** section? Do I just reuse the one from the [BeagleBone demo site](http://downloads.angstrom-distribution.org/demo/beaglebone/mkcard.txt)? Then there is an important steps section under **Finally booting GNU/Linux** that only contains the text "to be completed".

Does anybody know what additional things need to be done to boot into a Debian release for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content of [RPi Advanced Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup#Advanced_SD_card_setup) states that it is based on [BeagleBoardBeginners](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardBeginners) and [mkcard.txt](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/demo/beaglebone/mkcard.txt) is a script that formats and partitions an SD card. It appears that this script could be used for systems other than BeagleBoard but I am guessing that the Advanced Setup authors want to figure out what customizations, if any, may make sense for the RPi.

@AlexChamberlain pointed out and some [research confirms](http://imrannazar.com/Booting-Linux-from-Flash) the the VFAT partition is important for booting a Linux system from flash like that used with the RPi.

If you do not require instructions that generate an empty (but partitioned) filesystem on your SD card, you can download a pre-made image and setup an SD card more easily; see [How do I install an OS image onto an SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/931/86).

Comment: The FAT partition is absolutely required for the bootloader on the RPi.

Comment: @deaks +1 Thanks for the info, I was quite certain that was the correct file. I was hoping that this question would result in an answer that detailed the steps on creating your own build or that wiki getting completed.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what `makecard` is supposed to do. I guess it partitions the SD card - use `fdisk` - and copies the image on - download from the website and use `dd`.